# Tuning of hyperparameters of SVR

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, gridsearchcv

What is the better way of selecting the hyperparameters of SVR for tuning them using `GridSearchCV`? I learnt that the input to `GridSearchCV` is set of values for `C`, `gamma` and `epsilon`. The `GridSearchCV` algorithm evaluates each of these values and suggests the best among the set of values given to it as input. How to select the set of values to be given as input? Is there a better way of selecting them apart from trial and error? Resorting to trial and error is time consuming and also one might miss out optimal values of the Hyperparameters.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, good hyperparameters range depends on the problem. It is difficult to find one solution that fit all problems.

The [literature](http://adrem.uantwerpen.be/bibrem/pubs/IJCNN2007.pdf) recommends an `epsilon` between `1-e3` and `1`. Concerning the `C` parameter a good hyperparameter space would be between `1` and `100`. A `C` that is too large will simply overfit the training data.

The `gamma` is already calculated by scikit-learn `SVR`. I would not change it.

Don't forget that you can also tune the `kernel` and this might be the most important hyperparameter to tune.

To conclude, there is no free lunch when searching for the best hyperparameter ranges. The best option is to read literature and documenation as well as understanding each parameter impact.